# mount S3 buckets, scale out or scale up?

Tags: amazon-s3, ftp, fuse, smb, s3fs

maybe I should move this question to serverfault, but maybe not =)

I have an infra where I have multiple machines (eg FTP servers, get/put and Samba/NFS servers) that need to share out the same (HA) storage. So I figured to use s3fs and fuse. I got this all setup and this works fine, I have two servers each exposing the same bucket via FTP/SMB/NFS.

Now, when I have more and more servers that need access to the same bucket, what is the best alternative? Just let these other machines mount the same bucket (scale out) or put the working two machines in front of S3 and use the NFS/SMB shares from there (and thus scale up on the front machines)?

Any idea what is the best approach? Normally I tend to scale out, but I am not too familiar with s3fs and Fuse (or S3).

so: S3 <-> AppA, B and C | OR | S3 <-> NAS_WITH NFS/SMB/FTP <-> AppA, B and C

Any comments welcome!
Grtz,
Ronald

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to share files across these servers? If not, mounting the buckets on each server is likely more efficient (you don't have any common bottlenecks and single point of failure).

On the other hand, if you are not deploying your apps in EC2 *and* they often share the same set of files, then you maybe able to use s3fs' disk cache as a shared cache, in which case putting file servers in between can help. You need to be careful with eventual consistency and other caveats with caching, however.

If your workload is mostly streaming IO, then something like goofys (https://github.com/kahing/goofys) maybe more appropriate than s3fs. (disclaimer, I developed goofys).